# How Does EV Change As More Cards Come Up?

Tags: texas-hold-em, probability

I am trying to find a resource/simulator that tracks how EV changes as more cards get delt throughout the hand and then showing the overall EV (assuming an average of all the different EVs at each step) but am not having any luck finding information about this.

Could someone please explain how the EV progresses throughout the hand, and then what the realized EV is at the end of the hand?

Example:
Step 1: Dealt 2 Js - (EV at this step = ?)
Step 2: The flop comes and its 3, 5, 7 - (EV at this step = ?)
Step 3: The turn comes, another J shows up - (EV at this step = ?)
Step 4: The river comes and its another J - (EV at this step = ?)
Realized EV = average of EV at each step weighted by the probability of winning?

Comment: Expected Value (EV) can only be calculated if bets are involved. If you mean Equity (percentage of winning the hand) you can check out pokerstove.

Comment: I don't know of any software that shows EV step by step like this but it would not be too hard to calculate on your own, check out this website if you are interested in that: https://www.thepokerbank.com/strategy/mathematics/expected-value/calculate/

Answer (score 1):

propokertools can do this. Just go the the simulations tab and enter the cards you want. You can use an asterisk to simulate a random hand. I am attaching a screenshot of the scenarios you mentioned. [image: J's vs 357]

As a different user mentioned, your EV is a function of your bets and your equity, so this won't tell you your exact expected value, but it will help you calculate it.